# Proxypass from any subfolder

Tags: apache

I'm not that great at proxypass(reverse). So any help would be great.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to pass any subdirectory to the root url.

So hitting mydomain.com/xxxx would get passed to mydomain.com/

What would be the best way to achieve this.

Reasoning is currently we have 55 different variations. And I'd hate to have to create a ProxyPass(Reverse) line for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to reverse proxy all of this stuff since the domain never changes. But if for whatever reason you have, you **must** reverse proxy, you can use [`ProxyPassMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch) which works similar to `ProxyPass` except you can give it a regex pattern:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+)$ http://mydomain.com/
```

Still, seems to me what you really just want is to internally rewrite instead of sending an entirely new request on behalf of a single request:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.(php|html?)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ / [L]
```

---

> Each "sub-folder" is actually used to track where the user obtained the url (think tv, radio, etc) but we don't want to manage 50+ versions of a page. So the idea was to redirect it to the same page, capture the subdirectory value and use that info. Ideally a query string would be nice but we were told not to use them (readability I'm guessing)

If you use a reverse proxy, you lose the info from the landing page. That means if I go to, `http://foo.com/bar1`, and that gets reverse proxied to `http://foo.com/index.php`, the `index.php` script will not know that it was proxied from `/bar1` (though I think you can pass that along as proxied headers). So that kind of defeats the purpose. If you internally rewrite, like above, the browser is hidden from it all, and won't know that any internal routing has happened. You can also pass query strings if you like, since everything is completely hidden from the browser:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?subdir=$1 [L]
```

So with those rules, if someone goes to `http://foo.com/tv` and the `/tv` isn't a folder or file, it gets internally routed to `/index.php` and the "tv" is passed to the script as the GET parameter "subdir".

Comment: Good question and maybe I'm not sure what I should do either... proxypass seemed like the right approach. Each "sub-folder" is actually used to track where the user obtained the url (think tv, radio, etc) but we don't want to manage 50+ versions of a page. So the idea was to redirect it to the same page, capture the subdirectory value and use that info. Ideally a query string would be nice but we were told not to use them (readability I'm guessing) If you have a better idea - I'm open :)

Comment: I seem to be getting the "it works" message when i browse to domain.com/index.html/1

Now I am currently doing this using xampp and I put it in the .htaccess file at root level.


`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.html?subdir=$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: @Veo If `/index.html` exists, then the conditions fail. The conditions say "any request for a file or directory that **does not exist**". Assuming that `index.html` exists, the rule never gets applied.

Comment: Sorry @Jon Lin, index.html is at the root directory - meaning that my pages should be rerouted to that page instead of index.php like your example suggests. I figured the rule would still apply if it was an .html file instead of a .php file. Not sure why I'm getting "it works" when I navigate to a directory that **doesn't** exist.

Comment: @Veo Probably because the `index.html` file is the apache default installation file, which just says "It Works". It's not a script so the query string parameter (`subdir`) is ignored. You need a script, not a static HTML file, if you plan on doing anything with the parameter.